# elfutils build error on mac: configure: error: __thread support required

Tags: macos, elf, binutils, dwarf

Instructions to repro:

```bash
$ git clone --depth=1  git://sourceware.org/git/elfutils.git
$ cd elfutils
$ autoreconf -i -f
$ ./configure
```

Error log:

```bash
...
checking whether the compiler generates build-ids... ./configure: line 6951: -n: command not found
no
configure: WARNING: compiler doesn't generate build-id by default
checking whether gcc supports -Wl,-z,relro... no
checking for __thread support... no
configure: error: __thread support required
```

What is missing here?

Machine details:
MacOS 12.3.1

Comment: `error: __thread support required` is caused by `ld: unknown option: --build-id`, since built ID is unspported on macOS. If you disable the forced build-id check in `configure.ac` and run `autoreconf`, it should be able continue. However, elfutils has *massive* portability problems. This is *one of the 20+ changes needed* to make elfutils build. Other problems include missing libraries like argp-standalone, obstack-standalone, `byteswap.h`, `strchrnul()`, `program_invocation_short_name`, `posix_fallocate()`, unsupported strong aliases, just to name a few.

Comment: Even after fixing all of these problems, I still haven't manage to get `elfutils` to build. The last problem I saw before giving up was missing `stdio_ext.h`, and who knows how many additional problems are waiting behind.